# Store Bresenham generated circle as polygon?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, bresenham

I'm generating circles using the [Midpoint circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm). I don't want to draw these circles. Instead, I want to store them as polygons. Obviously, the coordinates are in the wrong order so if I would draw these circles using e.g. [Graphics.DrawPolygon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0c4s09.aspx) the circle would become a mesh of lines.

**Q:** How can I modify the algorithm to generate a correctly defined polygon? Or, how can I create a valid polygon from a set of points (in this case belonging to a circle)?

**Update:** This did the trick.

```
var firstHalf = points.Where(p => p.Y >= cy).OrderBy(p => p.X);
var secondHalf = points.Where(p => p.Y < cy).OrderByDescending(p => p.X);

var polygon = new List<Point>();
polygon.AddRange(firstHalf);
polygon.AddRange(secondHalf);
```

Comment: That would certainly work, but I need 100% pixel accuracy for these circles. Hence, the midpoint algorithm is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the circle, it should be enough to sort the two halfs, e.g. sort in x above y_mid ascending and below y_mid descending. Togther those point should by your polygon.

Comment: This works. I believe the rasterization algorithm could indeed be changed to get the sorting done at once. However, this solution is good enough. Thanks :)